# How to show set of Checkbox based on a previous checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a form with a list of checkbox on it. When a user selects "Laboratory", I want the second list of checkbox to be shown. I dont want the second list of checkboxes to be shown until they have clicked on the "Laboratory" checkbox.

How do I accomplish this in Javascript or jQuery?

Here's the php code for first list of checkbox

```html
<?php
 $tsql = "select medTestName from medtest";
  $tstmt = $con->prepare($tsql);
  $tstmt->execute();
  $tstmt->bind_result($mtn);
$tstmt->store_result();
             
while ($tstmt->fetch()){
$d1= '<input type="checkbox" name="test[]"
                  value="'.$mtn.'">'.$mtn.'<br>';
echo $d1;
 }  
             
?>
```

Here's the image of database which is the first list of checkbox

[image]

Here's the image or the UI of the first list of checkbox

[image]

Here's my html code for the second list of checkbox

```html
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="1"><span>Complete Blood Count</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="2"><span>Blood Typing</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="3"><span>Urinalysis</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="4"><span>RPR/TPHA</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="5"><span>Hepatitis B screening</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="6"><span>Fasting Blood Sugar</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="7"><span>Creatinine</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="8"><span>Total Cholesterol(Low Cholesterol, High Cholesterol)</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="9"><span>Triglyceride</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="10"><span>VLDL</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="11"><span>Blood Uric Acid</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="12"><span>Anti-HAV Igm Screening</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="13"><span>Anti HBaAg</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="14"><span>Drug & Alcohol Test</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="15"><span>Stool Culture</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like below,

Also you can make it dynamic using `php`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //initially hide all the sub lists
  $(".sublists").children().each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("data-sub-list") == "true") {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });

  // when you click the checkbox show Radiology,Radiology or ect.
  $("input[name=test]").click(function() {
    var list = $(this).attr("data-list");
    console.log(list);
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
      $("#" + list + "").show();
    } else {
      $("#" + list + "").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-7">
  <input type="checkbox" name="test" id="Radiology" value="Radiology" data-list="Radiology-list">Radiology
  <input type="checkbox" name="test" id="Laboratory" value="Laboratory" data-list="Laboratory-list">Laboratory
</div>
<div class="sublists">
  <div id="Laboratory-list" data-sub-list="true">
    <h4>Laboratory list</h4>

    <div class="col-xs-7">
      <input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="Creatinine">Creatinine
      <input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="Triglyceride">Triglyceride
      <input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="VLDL">VLDL
    </div>

  </div>
  <div id="Radiology-list" data-sub-list="true">
    <h4>Radiology list</h4>

    <div class="col-xs-7">
      <input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="one">One
      <input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="two">Two
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can I call the id when I'm using php?

Comment: @Vista you can use `data` attributes to make it happen with `foreach` any kind of a loop.

Comment: thanks!, but my problem is that the first list of checkbox is in php code, so the list of checkbox has being bind, so if I apply the javascript, not only the checkbox of laboratory can show the 2nd list of checkbox :(

Comment: @Vista check my answer... click on **Radiology** and **Laboratory** it will show seprate **lists**.

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="test[]"> which calls all the first checkbox

Answer (score 0):

In all cases, you have to generate it (in a hidden `ul` for example) and show it with jQuery like $("#mydiv").toggle();
Here is the jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/6ufzban3/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JQuery `.toggle()` function to show/hide elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("value") == "lab") {
      $(".labboxes").toggle();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.labboxes {
  margin: 10px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox">Radiology
<input type="checkbox" value="lab">Laboratory
<div class="labboxes">
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="topic"><span>Triglyceride</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="topic"><span>VLDL</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="topic"><span>Creatinine</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<?php
    $tsql = "select medTestName from medtest";
    $tstmt = $con->prepare($tsql);
    $tstmt->execute();
    $tstmt->bind_result($mtn);
    $tstmt->store_result();
           
    while ($tstmt->fetch()){
        $d1= '<input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="'.$mtn.'">'.$mtn.'<br>';
        echo $d1;
    }  
             
?>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.